# count the occurence of values in a column in tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a data set with 900 000 rows. There's a column "event_id". I want to create a table of occurences of event_id.

```
occured once = 63K
occured twice = 114K
occured thrice = 54k
```

and so on.

How can I do this in Tableau?

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lakh* that are not globally understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step_1 = drag event_id to rows

step_2 = drag *filename.csv(count)* to TEXT.